# 100 csv files to be analyse with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io, csv

I have used MATLAB before but used it to analyses data from `*.txt` file. Can someone help me out how can I program the MATLAB to read all the 100 csv file. Each csv file have 14 columns, and about 10,000 rows. These csv files only contain numbers, no text.

All I want is to read columns F,G and H. And from the to calculate the average value for column F, G and H, Then again average the value for the whole 100 csv files for column F, G and H.

Comment: ok, why the -1? OP is just trying to get some help and has stated the question fairly clearly.

Answer (score 11):

You can enumerate all the files in a directory by doing

```
files= dir('folder_wilth_your_csv_files\*.csv');
```

And then you traverse that with

```
num_files = length(files);
for i=1:num_files
     data=csvread(files(i).name)
end
```

[csvread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/csvread.html) will allow you to read in only a certain row and col range if you want. Once you have your data, averaging is the trivial part.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [dlmread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dlmread.html) or [csvread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/csvread.html)?